# Significance Test for Distributions Across Unequal Time Periods

Tags: distributions, proportion

I am looking at monthly death data and am trying to understand if there's a sound way to determine if the patterns in the current month are different from the same month in previous years. For example, is the proportion of male deaths different in December 2022 than it was for December 2017-2021? What would be the best way to statistically test for this since the time periods are not equal? In other words, would it still be correct to do a 2-sample test of proportions to compare the proportion of male deaths in December 2022 vs. proportion for December 2017-2021? That is:

Male deaths in December 2022/all deaths in December 2022
vs.
Male deaths in December 2017-2021/all deaths December 2017-2021

Or is it best to compare Dec 2022 to the average for Dec 2017-2021, though I'm not sure what the best statistical test would be since Dec 2022 would not be an average.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have individual data $d_i$ for 6 months (and presumably an uncertainty $\sigma_i$ on each number).  If that is the case (and if you can assume the uncertainties are gaussian), why not take as null hypothesis that the 6 months are random gaussian fluctuations around a shared value $v$, then minimize $\chi^2(v) = \sum_i \frac{(d_i - v)^2}{\sigma_i^2}$, and then calculate the p-value to determine if the data are consistent with the null hypothesis?